# Django: foreign key form input

Tags: django, forms

Is it possible to have a form field that allows you to choose from existing instances (I apologize if instance is the wrong word) of a foreign key model or add a new one? For example, in an image sharing app, there may be an image upload page. When uploading, you can choose an existing tag to assign to the image or create a new one. The models could be as follows:

```
class Tag(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128, unique = True)

class Image(models.Model):
    tag = models.ForeignKey(Tag)
```

Answer (score 0):

To have a dropdown list with existing tags use a [ModelForm](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/forms/modelforms/) for your image form and you could add Tag Form to create new tags or a new_tag input to your image form. According to your model I'll do something like:

`Class ImageForm(ModelForm):
   new_tag = forms.CharField(required=False)
    Class Meta:
        model = Image
        fields = ['tag']`

Comment: Please could you demonstrate what that looks like? Could they both be within the same form?